# Chrome uses direct HTTP sockets/not TCP ones

Tags: java, sockets, google-chrome, applet

I am writing a (sort of) distributed application using applets (game playing). It is deep into the implementation, so the design is more or less fixed.

However, when I connect to peers using Java sockets (at least in Chrome), it is trying to connect to http://. Why is that happening?

It is actually succeeding connection, however, writing data is also seems fine. Reading is failing (mostly because it is expecting HTTP payload). Why is this happening? Is there a way to change it? (The app is not yet working in other browsers).

Code Snippet:

```
private IoSession(InetSocketAddress peerAddr, 
                  IoHandlerAdapter handler, 
                  boolean synch, 
                  int connectTimeOut) 
throws IOException { 
    this.handler = handler; 
    try { 
        mySocket = new Socket(peerAddr.getAddress(), peerAddr.getPort());     
        System.out.println("Socket is done to " + peerAddr.getPort());
```

Comment: Can you show us your code because `new Socket(hostname, port);` doesn't do this?

Comment: private IoSession(InetSocketAddress peerAddr, IoHandlerAdapter handler, boolean synch, int connectTimeOut) throws IOException {
        this.handler = handler; 

        try {
            mySocket = new Socket(peerAddr.getAddress(), peerAddr.getPort());
System.out.println("Socket is done to " + peerAddr.getPort());

Comment: The println says it. But before that, it prints saying "Connect http:// ipaddr:port/" in the applet's java console

Comment: This suggests the message is incorrect. The Socket itself assumes there is no protocol and wouldn't work correctly if it did (even for HTTP requests)

Comment: The title is wrong. There are no "HTTP sockets". HTTP is a protocol in different (higher) layer and it uses TCP/IP beneath.

Comment: ok, I guess it is solved. I understand there are no HTTP sockets. The problem is elsewhere, and I could solve it. It has nothing to do with HTTP. The message is wrong in Java console, in Chrome at least. I will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I guess it is solved. I understand there are no HTTP sockets. The problem is elsewhere, and I could solve it. It has nothing to do with HTTP. The message is wrong in Java console, in Chrome at least.